# standard deviation

Tags: probability

It has been reported that household in the west  spend an annual average of \$6050 for groceries.Assume a normal distrubition with a standard deviation of \$1500.

(a) What  is the probability  that a randomly selected house hold spends moree than \$6350 for groceries?

(b)How much  money  would a western  house hold  have to spend  on groceries per year in order  to be at  the 99th  percentile (ie only 1 percent of Western  household would spend more on groceries)?

Comment: Did you try something to solve the exercise? Is maybe a "homework"?

Comment: no this was just sent to me via e-mail from my professor.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The normal distribution is described by a probability distribution function
$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp \left( -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).$$

The probability a randomly selected house spends *less than* \$6350 is given by
$$\int_{-\infty}^{6350} f_X(x)\ dx.$$

Simply perform a rescaling of $x$ to get it to standard normal form, and use the lookup table you most certainly have access to. Part (b) is done similarly.

Do you know how to re-scale a variable in an integral?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. No we have not been taught  re-scaleing as yet

Comment: I thank you so much for your detailed explanation..i see where i went really wrong...A thousand thanks to you..:)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple normal distribution. You are given two things:
$$\mu=\$6050$$
$$\sigma = \$1500$$

From this, you can get the z-score. The z-score is modeled as:

$$z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$$

The z-score will tell you how many standard deviations you are away from the mean, at some value $x$. From the z-score, you can obtain the area that's under the normal curve. Because it's a normal distribution, this area will be the probability of landing in that range (recall that the total area is $1$).

The first thing we have is that an household spends more than $\$6350$. In other words, we want the area from $x=6350 \text{ to } \infty$. We can calculate the z-score to be:

$$z=\frac{6350-6050}{1500}=\frac{1}{5}$$

Now to get the area, you can use 3 things - an integral (you probably don't want to do that), use a chart (that has z-scores and their p-values, which are the areas), OR use your calculator. Your calculator has a function called `normalcdf()`, that has two overloaded methods: `normalcdf(z_min, z_max)` and `normalcdf(min, max, mean, std_deviation)`. So in reality, you don't even need to find the z-score. But you'll have to show your work on your exams so you might as well.

When we use `normalcdf()` to get the area, it comes up to be $\approx 0.420740$ which means that the probability is $\approx 42.0740\%$ That's the answer for part (a).

Part (b) deals with percentiles. For this you'll have to find the z-score in which the area below it is $0.99\;(99\%)$. Because anything at that z-score will be at the 99th percentile. Again, you can use a chart, but you probably won't need to. You can use your calculator's `invNorm()` function.

You can play around with that function, and see that `invNorm(0.5)`, for example, will give you $0$ because the mean ($z=0$) splits the distribution in half. Then you get the answer for the z-score at the 99th percentile to be $\approx 2.3263$. We don't want to find areas now, we want to find how much money that person would need to have to be at that z-score. Easy; just solve for $x$:

$$2.3263=\frac{x-6050}{1500}$$
$$\therefore x \approx \$9539.5218$$

And that's it! A person who spends approximately $\$9539.52$ is at the 99th percentile. Meaning, only him and 1% of the population spend that much or higher.